# Duplicating a string in C (Include memory allocating, pointers, etc.)

Tags: c, string, memory, duplicates

This is the code I have so far:

```
char * duplicate(char *str)
{
    int len = strlen(str) + 1;
    char *ptr;
    ptr = (char *)malloc(len);
    strcpy(ptr, str);
    str = (char *)realloc((void *)str, len * 2 * sizeof(char));
    strcat(str, ptr);
    free((void *)ptr);
    present(str);
    return(str);
}
```

**sidenote**: I know I should be checking if the memory is actually allocated, I will do so later.

The program asks the user to input a string, proceeds to double it and prints out the new string.
`present->a` function I made so it would print the string out.

Now my thought process was as follows:

1) Allocate memory to a placeholder pointer, copy `str` string onto `ptr`

2) Reallocate memory for `str`, now with double the size

3) Using `strcat` to copy the string

4) Freeing `ptr` memory

Output should be as follows:

```
string input by users for example: "Hi"

output: "HiHi"
```

If we run the function again output should be: `"HiHiHiHi"`

The problem I am facing is, after running the function around 2-4 times (depends on the input string size) the program will crash, it will say it had a trigger point and something along the lines of: `"wntdll.pdb not loaded".`

I believe it has something to do with the memory, because if I am trying to duplicate larger strings, it will simply crash after the first time.

Am I allocating memory properly? I am not sure what to do at this point.

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Comment: [`strdup`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/experimental/dynamic/strdup)

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid all the boilerplate by just using [`strdup`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/experimental/dynamic/strdup):

```
char *s1 = "String";
char *s2 = strdup(s1);
...
free(s2);
```

Your function would become:

```
char* duplicate(char const *str) {
  char *ptr = strdup(str);
  ptr = (char*) realloc(ptr, 2 * strlen(str) + 1);
  strcat(ptr, str);

  return ptr;
}
```

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d9896c5d02809440)

Comment: Thanks, it does clear stuff up! any idea about my other problem? because the string gets duplicated, but crashes if it gets too long.

Comment: @Dimakossover how long?

Comment: If the input string is : "hi", it will copy it twice, so it becomes hi->hihi->hihihihi->hihihihihihihihi->At this point, it will crash. (after calling the duplicate function again.)

Comment: Making an educated guess, I think that returning the input string in your version is not sane. You see, you're actually changing the input buffer.

Comment: Hello @101010 i actually forgot to pass over the new value to ptr_s in main from the code, now that I've done it it's all good, no crashes and very smooth, thank you for you attention and help, greatly appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

You don't need that extra allocation:

```
char * duplicate(char *str)
{
    size_t len = strlen(str);
    char *ret = realloc(str, 2*len+1); //assuming no overflow
    if(ret){
        memcpy(ret+len, ret, len);
        ret[2*len]=0;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is very informative! my question is, what does memcpy doe? (obviously it copies memory blocks) but how can i recreate without the use of this function? thanks in advance.

Comment: After using your code, same thing happens, i can duplicate a string a few times and after the 3rd-5th time program crashes.

Comment: @Dimakossover Show us the entire code. Maybe you do something illegal like `duplicate("foo");` or `char *foo = "foo"; duplicate(foo);`. (You see why that's illegal, right?)

Comment: hi @DavidSchwartz i copied the relevant code here:http://pastebin.com/VssF3wBe , thanks in advance.

Comment: @Dimakossover Since you have so much code that messes with `ptr_s`, the bug could be anywhere. I'd look at `get` first. (Or give us enough code to reproduce the problem.)

Comment: With 6 duplications you need 64 times as (2^6) as much memory. If your strings are large, the allocations might be failing. Don't forget to check the return codes to makes sure you're not getting NULLs.

Comment: this is my get() function : http://pastebin.com/AAfrdXKL , i did notice that the maximum length of my initial string input should not be larger then 250, (LEN is defined 250) , but after getting input from user once, i do not mess with get() no more.